# Google Calendar displaying the same events for different users. Why?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I am trying to use Google Calendar. I have different accounts registered in the Google Calendar Android app. Each of these corresponds to a different phone user in my household or to one of my virtual accounts.

What I can't understand, is, why are my calendar events staying the same when I switch users in the circle in the upper right-hand corner of the app?

The following images display the same calendar entries for both of the users I have switched in the app.

[image: Google Calendar under one user].[image: Google Calendar under a different user]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a function of Google Calendar. Most people want to make sure they can see their *entire* schedule at a glance, including events that belong to different accounts.

If you pull out the sidebar from the left hand side (either by sliding from the side or using the "hamburger" (three lines) menu) you can see which calendars are being displayed from each account and toggle them on and off with the checkboxes. The selections you make with these checkboxes are "sticky" per account, so when you switch to another account, you can make a different selection there.

Please note that some calendars may be hidden from this menu at first; they'll need to be enabled under Settings > [pick an account] > Show more > tap on calendar > Sync.